# How can I localize the Entity Framework build-in validation messages/exceptions?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Beside the annotation-based validation mechanism EF provides the so-called "Facets". Meaning on a string property you could have a "Max Length" Facet (through the EF model configuration) where you specify a max-length of 80 chars. Most often this is done automatically by EF when you use a database first approach.

If now the property contains more than the specified number of chars, EF will throw a DbEntityValidationResult with the message

> [PropName]: The field [PropName] must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '80'.

My question: How can I localize such message??? I'd need it in german and italian as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maarten Balliauw wrote a blog blog about it:

[Localize ASP.NET MVC 2 DataAnnotations validation messages](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/05/Localize-ASPNET-MVC-2-DataAnnotations-validation-messages.aspx)

Update your classes to use the `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName` parameters instead of the ErrorMessage parameter that you normally pass.

Also, you can localize your DisplayNameAttributes; here's a Stackoverflow post which explains how to do it: [Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

**Update**

I think if you install the .NET Framework Language Pack these standard messages should be translated for you.

A caveat (happened to me): [ASP.NET MVC 3 localized validation messages work on my machine, but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636332/asp-net-mvc-3-localized-validation-messages-work-on-my-machine-but-not-on-serve)

Comment: I'd prefer not to decorate all my entities with validation annotations just for the purpose of localizing the validation msgs. But I thought about the language packs as well before...Guess I have to give it a try