# Usage of Entity Framework resource.dlls

Tags: c#, resources, entity-framework-6

In my Windows Forms client application I would like to show localized Entity Framework validation messages. Following StackOverflow question shows, how to localize the validations with custom messages:

[How can I localize the Entity Framework build-in validation messages/exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892377/how-can-i-localize-the-entity-framework-build-in-validation-messages-exceptions)

But on NuGet you can also find satelite resource assemblies for localization like

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.de/6.1.3 or https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.fr/6.1.3.

When I install such a package, the application still shows the english validation messaged allthough the culture is switched to the specific cultures like "de-DE". There seems something missing to tell Entity Framework that it should use these resource files.

Any idea that could help?

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework only uses the english language when in Visual Studio. But when the application runs without Visual Studio, the localization works.