# uiCulture does not work on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I use ASP.NET, EF 6.0.2, MVC 5.1.1.
In web.config I set culture and uiCulture:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="de-CH" uiCulture="de" enableClientBasedCulture="false"  />
</system.web>
```

When I run the application locally, then the validation messages are shown in German correctly.
When I publish the project to the webserver, the validation message are shown always in English.

But the printing of:

```
Culture: @System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString()
UI Culture: @System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString()
```

shows correct the setted 'de-CH' and 'de'...

The validation takes place on the server instead (not client side). Because the validation message after submitting the form occurs

What I want, is to set the language of the application fix to German-Switzerland.

Comment: What is the `eval` you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the validation should be on the server

Comment: Should this be the same mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636332/asp-net-mvc-3-localized-validation-messages-work-on-my-machine-but-not-on-serve Have I to install Language Pack on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved: The German language pack was not installed on the server.